# ajax post not working to new page in mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I would like to post the result of a sortable list to another page using an ajax request. How do I do this. Right now it is working on the same page when i set it to a document.getElementbyId but I am not familiar with how ajax post request work. Do I need something on the other page to retentive the information that's posted?

```
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');


        }
    }).disableSelection();
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        var r = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
        var a = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize", {
            attribute: "id"
        })

        $.ajax({
            data: (r,a),
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/home/print_results'
        });

        ;

            console.log(r, a);

            $('#selectfeatures').html('<p>' + r, a + '</p>') = sessionStorage.rank;



    });
```

here is the html

```
  <ul id="sortable" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left:190px;">

        <li id="fit" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>FIT</li>

        <li id="durability" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>DURABILITY</li>

        <li id="framematerial" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>FRAME MATERIAL</li>

        <li id="lenstype" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>LENS TYPE</li>

        <li id="lightweight" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>LIGHT WEIGHT</li>

        <li id="style" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>STYLE</li>

        <li id="lensthinness" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>LENS THINNESS</li>

        <li id="lenscolor" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>LENS COLOR</li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there is any js errors. Check the network tab to see whether the call is made and what is the response

Comment: Nope there are no errors. the array displays in the console. Does the ajax request it look correct to you. When i go to the print results page no text shows up. Do I have to build it out it some way?

Comment: Did you check the network tab ? Do you see the request for the ajax call ?

Comment: Yeah it says status 200 type xhr. but i dont see where it shows up

Comment: And your controller? You have a controller called print_results?

Comment: your ajax method returns a response. you  need to use the response and update the dom (as needed) in your `success` or `done` event. What you want when the ajax call returns a response ?

Comment: the controller is called home. that's why in the ajax call i put url: '/home/print_results'

Comment: I want the list in this case (r,a) to be returned to the new page called print_results. I'm glad to know the ajax status is correct, i just need to display the actual data that is passed. How do I update the dome or upon success post the #selectfeatures.html in a div on the print_results page.

Comment: do i need response headers?

Comment: If you want to show the new page, why doing ajax ? Just do a normal form submit. You should use ajax when you do not want to reload/navigate to a new page.

Comment: the ui sortable is done with javascript and not with entity framework. Plus its only like 8 words. I don't want to navigate to the new page until the very end. if i do a form submit, i think i have to navigate to that page right away.     all it is is an unordered list. <ul> with <li> inside of it

Comment: First thing I see: data: (r,a).  make that data: {r: r, a: a}.  That will give you $_POST['r'] and $_POST['a'] in php

Comment: this is mvc though, will that still work emmanuel?

Comment: @Shyju the form data on the network tab shows the list that i want as well in the DOM. I just want to be able put that in the html page.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, you need to add more lines to your [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call. Your current [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call just sends the data to the url provided:

```
$.ajax({
    data: (r,a),
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/home/print_results'
});
```

If you look within the console > network tab, you should see a call to /home/print_results. That call should have your data, meaning the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) post is doing what you asked it to do (I would only pass r, since it should have all the data from your form).

The next step comes in the form of "handling the data" passed to home/print_results. Code within that page would add it to your db, or maybe do some calculation and spit back the result to same function so you can handle it on the same page.

I assume you just want to show those values on a new page, and not save them, so you dont really need to do an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call for that. Opening a new window with the injected html should work out (Check out the open function in javascript).

If what you need is to gather some kind of result or message out of that page you are calling, you need to add a "done" parameter to the call:

```
$.ajax({
    data: r,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/home/print_results',
    done: function(result){
    // enter code here
    }
});
```

Here is where you would get your result information from the post you just made.

Remember, POST is essentially passing data. how you handle said data is up to the code getting the post.

As far as saving the information, it would depend on your application config. You need to pass the needed form data to the location where your application can handle it. In the following case of nodeJS you can see that the request object has a body parameter where you could handle the data.

```
app.post('/save', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.data);
  var data = new Data({name: 'Name', age: 25});
  data.save();
});
```

on the above example we are using a mongodb model. Again, it depends on your MVC framework what the save call will be. From there you would just need to grab the data back from the db into the page call you want displaying this information.

Comment: Thanks for helping but it still isn't the working solution. Yes I would like to just show those values on a new page, but that's only when I get to that particular page. Plus, I still haven't passed the data yet                                                $.ajax({
                data: r,
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/home/print_results',
                done: function (result) {
                    document.getElementbyId("newtest").innerHTML = r;
                }
            });

Comment: what function goes inside of the done(result){    }  ??

Comment: Sounds like you need to save the data. Depending on the MVC framework you are using, you need to call the function call that saves data onto your storage. 

I'll edit my post to add more information.